# Project is not linking GLFW

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, makefile, glfw

so I have a project with multiple dependencies of the following structure:

Dependencies
 - Glad
 - GLFW
 - ImGui
Engine
Sandbox

Engine includes the dependencies and Sandbox includes Engine

Project files are generated by premake5.
This compiles and runs perfectly under Windows, but today i tried to port it to linux.
I generated makefiles by using the linux version of premake.
All files do compile successfully, but when the linking process starts i get the following error:

> ==== Building Sandbox (debug) ====
>   Linking Sandbox
>   ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a(context.o): In function `_glfwRefreshContextAttribs':
>   /home/netcode/Engine/Engine/vendor/GLFW/src/context.c:361: undefined reference to`_glfwPlatformGetTls'
>   ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a(context.o): In function `glfwMakeContextCurrent':<br>
>   /home/netcode/Engine/Engine/vendor/GLFW/src/context.c:614: undefined reference to`_glfwPlatformGetTls'
>   ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a(context.o): In function `glfwGetCurrentContext':
>   /home/netcode/Engine/Engine/vendor/GLFW/src/context.c:638: undefined reference to`_glfwPlatformGetTls'
>   ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a(context.o): In function `glfwSwapInterval':
>   /home/netcode/Engine/Engine/vendor/GLFW/src/context.c:664: undefined reference to`_glfwPlatformGetTls'
>   ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a(context.o): In function `glfwExtensionSupported':
>   /home/netcode/Engine/Engine/vendor/GLFW/src/context.c:682: undefined reference to`_glfwPlatformGetTls'...

and so on...

this is the final makefile:

```
# Alternative GNU Make project makefile autogenerated by Premake

ifndef config
  config=debug
endif

ifndef verbose
  SILENT = @
endif

.PHONY: clean prebuild

SHELLTYPE := posix
ifeq (.exe,$(findstring .exe,$(ComSpec)))
    SHELLTYPE := msdos
endif

# Configurations
# #############################################

RESCOMP = windres
INCLUDES += -I../Engine/vendor/spdlog/include -I../Engine/src -I../Engine/vendor -I../Engine/vendor/glm -Isrc
FORCE_INCLUDE +=
ALL_CPPFLAGS += $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
ALL_RESFLAGS += $(RESFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
LINKCMD = $(CXX) -o "$@" $(OBJECTS) $(RESOURCES) $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
define PREBUILDCMDS
endef
define PRELINKCMDS
endef
define POSTBUILDCMDS
endef

ifeq ($(config),debug)
TARGETDIR = ../bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/Sandbox
TARGET = $(TARGETDIR)/Sandbox
OBJDIR = ../bin-int/Debug-linux-x86_64/Sandbox
DEFINES += -DENGINE_DEBUG
ALL_CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -g
ALL_CXXFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -g -std=c++17
LIBS += ../bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/Engine/libEngine.a ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a ../Engine/vendor/Glad/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/Glad/libGlad.a ../Engine/vendor/imgui/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/ImGui/libImGui.a -lXrandr -lXi -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -ldl -lpthread -lstdc++fs
LDDEPS += ../bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/Engine/libEngine.a ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a ../Engine/vendor/Glad/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/Glad/libGlad.a ../Engine/vendor/imgui/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/ImGui/libImGui.a
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS) -L/usr/lib64 -m64

else ifeq ($(config),release)
TARGETDIR = ../bin/Release-linux-x86_64/Sandbox
TARGET = $(TARGETDIR)/Sandbox
OBJDIR = ../bin-int/Release-linux-x86_64/Sandbox
DEFINES += -DENGINE_RELEASE
ALL_CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -O2
ALL_CXXFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -O2 -std=c++17
LIBS += ../bin/Release-linux-x86_64/Engine/libEngine.a ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Release-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a ../Engine/vendor/Glad/bin/Release-linux-x86_64/Glad/libGlad.a ../Engine/vendor/imgui/bin/Release-linux-x86_64/ImGui/libImGui.a -lXrandr -lXi -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -ldl -lpthread -lstdc++fs
LDDEPS += ../bin/Release-linux-x86_64/Engine/libEngine.a ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Release-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a ../Engine/vendor/Glad/bin/Release-linux-x86_64/Glad/libGlad.a ../Engine/vendor/imgui/bin/Release-linux-x86_64/ImGui/libImGui.a
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS) -L/usr/lib64 -m64 -s

else ifeq ($(config),dist)
TARGETDIR = ../bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/Sandbox
TARGET = $(TARGETDIR)/Sandbox
OBJDIR = ../bin-int/Dist-linux-x86_64/Sandbox
DEFINES += -DENGINE_DIST
ALL_CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -O2
ALL_CXXFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -m64 -O2 -std=c++17
LIBS += ../bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/Engine/libEngine.a ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a ../Engine/vendor/Glad/bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/Glad/libGlad.a ../Engine/vendor/imgui/bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/ImGui/libImGui.a -lXrandr -lXi -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -ldl -lpthread -lstdc++fs
LDDEPS += ../bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/Engine/libEngine.a ../Engine/vendor/GLFW/bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/GLFW/libGLFW.a ../Engine/vendor/Glad/bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/Glad/libGlad.a ../Engine/vendor/imgui/bin/Dist-linux-x86_64/ImGui/libImGui.a
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS) -L/usr/lib64 -m64 -s

else
  $(error "invalid configuration $(config)")
endif

# Per File Configurations
# #############################################


# File sets
# #############################################

OBJECTS :=

OBJECTS += $(OBJDIR)/Sandbox2D.o
OBJECTS += $(OBJDIR)/SandboxApp.o

# Rules
# #############################################

all: $(TARGET)
    @:

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(LDDEPS) | $(TARGETDIR)
    $(PRELINKCMDS)
    @echo Linking Sandbox
    $(SILENT) $(LINKCMD)
    $(POSTBUILDCMDS)

$(TARGETDIR):
    @echo Creating $(TARGETDIR)
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)
else
    $(SILENT) mkdir $(subst /,\\,$(TARGETDIR))
endif

$(OBJDIR):
    @echo Creating $(OBJDIR)
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
else
    $(SILENT) mkdir $(subst /,\\,$(OBJDIR))
endif

clean:
    @echo Cleaning Sandbox
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) rm -f  $(TARGET)
    $(SILENT) rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
else
    $(SILENT) if exist $(subst /,\\,$(TARGET)) del $(subst /,\\,$(TARGET))
    $(SILENT) if exist $(subst /,\\,$(OBJDIR)) rmdir /s /q $(subst /,\\,$(OBJDIR))
endif

prebuild: | $(OBJDIR)
    $(PREBUILDCMDS)

ifneq (,$(PCH))
$(OBJECTS): $(GCH) | $(PCH_PLACEHOLDER)
$(GCH): $(PCH) | prebuild
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    $(SILENT) $(CXX) -x c++-header $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -o "$@" -MF "$(@:%.gch=%.d)" -c "$<"
$(PCH_PLACEHOLDER): $(GCH) | $(OBJDIR)
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) touch "$@"
else
    $(SILENT) echo $null >> "$@"
endif
else
$(OBJECTS): | prebuild
endif


# File Rules
# #############################################

$(OBJDIR)/Sandbox2D.o: src/Sandbox2D.cpp
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    $(SILENT) $(CXX) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) $(FORCE_INCLUDE) -o "$@" -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c "$<"
$(OBJDIR)/SandboxApp.o: src/SandboxApp.cpp
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    $(SILENT) $(CXX) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) $(FORCE_INCLUDE) -o "$@" -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c "$<"

-include $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)
ifneq (,$(PCH))
  -include $(PCH_PLACEHOLDER).d
endif
```

any guesses?

Comment: How did you build/configure GLFW on Linux?

Comment: @Botje i forked the glfw github repository and added it as a git submodule

Comment: Yes, but how did you _build_ it? The function you're missing is supposed to be present if GLFW was configured on a Unix-like system.

Comment: @Botje i build it using _make_ or what do you mean?

Comment: i installed the packages `libxcursor-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxi-dev libglew-dev xorg-dev`

Comment: Glfw uses cmake for its build system, so you should have invoked cmake at some point. Can you redo that step on Linux and show the output?

Comment: Im pretty new to makefiles so im not really sure how to build only glfw using cmake and the rest using premake5 / gmake2

Comment: You have files in `vendor/GLFW/bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/GLFW/`. How did they get there? What commands did you use? This has nothing to do with "new at make", just basic observation.

Comment: I compiled GLFW using the command "make" the file in there is "libGLFW.a".
I made a premake5 file that works perfectly in windows. then i copied everything to linux and generated a makefile using "premake5 gmake" and started making by using "make"
every dependency compiles successfully. just when it comes to linking it fails

Comment: [GLFW does not ship with a Makefile](https://github.com/glfw/glfw), only a CMake file. So at _some_ point you (or whatever build system/script you use) must have  generated Makefiles (very probably by invoking `cmake`). Please redo that step on Linux.

Comment: i did. but as the command i used was `premake5 gmake2` i assume it generated a Makefile for gmake2

Comment: i did. but as the command i used was `premake5 gmake2` i assume it generated a Makefile for gmake2

Comment: So I find myself asking for the fourth time: how did your build system generate the Makefile for GLFW? Without that information we cannot help you fix this. If you cannot figure it out, please upload your project somewhere we can look at and try for ourselves.